# Why PATINDEX not returning leading zero to extract numbers from a string in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `patindex` to extract numbers from a field's value of a table as below

```
 select SUBSTRING(FieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', FieldName), 10)
```

but it is not returning leading zero of my string. Say I have something as below

```
select SUBSTRING('0گ 125', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'گ 0125'), 10)
```

It just returns `125` while I expected to be `0125`,what is wrong with my query?

Comment: It seems to be because the arabic characters in your text are making SQL server read it backwards. If you `SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'گ 0125')` you get 3, not 1.

Comment: Yes, that field contains arabic characters.how can i fix this issue?

Comment: even stranger is this seems exactly the same but i get "0125 ?" for a response:  select SUBSTRING('0125 گ', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', '0125 گ'), 10)

Comment: im still confused and cannot wrap my head around it .